# What is best experience level for enchanting fishing rod

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Question is fairly understandable from title. I wanted to enchant fishing rod .I have 2 questions to ask

1) at what level **lure** enchantment is available?

2) What is best experience level (in **Minecraft 1.7.2** all experience is used in enchanting) for enchanting fishing rod?

Comment: This article might help you figuring out: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Enchantment_mechanics
http://www.minecraftenchantmentcalculator.com/
http://minecraft.tools/en/enchant.php

Comment: That site stated that lure 1 has 18% chance on level 20

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you are actually looking for enchantment probabilities:
[image: fishing rod enchantment probabilities]
Note that the lines of `Lure I` and `Luck of the Sea I` overlap (same for `II` and `III`). This means that the probability of getting `Lure` is the same as the probability of getting `Luck of the Sea`.

To answer you questions:

1) The lure enchantment is available on level 12, but the probability of getting it is less than 1%

2) The answer to the second question depends on what you actually want to achieve. Assuming you want the best chance of getting `Lure` and/or `Luck of the Sea` in a single enchantment, it is best to enchant on level 30. The combined probability of getting any `Lure` (`I`, `II`, or `III`) is 53% at level 30. Same for `Luck of the Sea`:
[image: fishing rod lure combined probability]

Comment: Thanks. So lure 1 starts from level 12. I have current level 22. So i am going to need many cows for leather and i will enchant fishing rod.